# The "og:image" property must be provided explicitly

Tags: php, facebook, share

We developed a website and follow the guidelines to share pages in Facebook adding og: tags like:

```
   <meta property="og:image" content="https://plusweb.net.br/uploads/blog/ebe1ea2dc941fa2bca03196bf9becc0a.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="As 5 melhores plataformas para automação de marketing"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Atualmente, um elemento-chave para todas as empresas, que garantir&aacute; longevidade e sa&uacute;de para seus neg&oacute;cios, &eacute; a automa&ccedil;&atilde;o de marketing. Quando criei minha ag&ecirc;ncia de marketing e comecei a empreender, vivi muitas dificuldades que poderiam ter sido ev"/>            
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Plus Web Marketing Digital Integrado">
```

Even so Facebook Debugger return:

- The "og:image" property must be provided explicitly
- Also 206 Code

We searched and checked all we could and still did not found why Facebook keep returning error

We searched and checked all we could and still did not found why Facebook keep returning error

Anyone could help me solve this issue?

Comment: So what page URL did you actually test, that gave you errors? The debug tool appears to have no issue reading the image itself, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fplusweb.net.br%2Fuploads%2Fblog%2Febe1ea2dc941fa2bca03196bf9becc0a.jpg

Comment: This is the URL https://plusweb.net.br/blog/48/as-5-melhores-plataformas-para-automacao-de-marketing . In debugger shows the image but when shared into Facebook the image dissapear.

Comment: When I try to post that on Facebook, it shows the image fine in the preview, but then the resulting post doesn't show it. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: The debug tool for some reason still says _"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."_, although it actually shows the image.

Comment: Yes. Very weird. We tried several approaches and nothing works.

Comment: We solved the problem inserting the tags as the very first lines after the <head> element.  God damn it Facebook!